# An app needs iphone4 to run, do I need to set some key in the plist file to exclude iphone3 and others?

Tags: iphone

My app needs iphone4 to run, do I need to set some key in the plist file to exclude iphone3 and other devices when I publish it in the itunes store.

Comment: Why does it require iPhone 4? Would it work on an iPhone 4-based iPod Touch when that comes out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the base SDK of your project to SDK 4+ and then make sure you set the 'iPhone OS Deployment Target' to 4.0. in your project/target settings. I appreciate this will simply limit the devices running < OS4, but it's worth doing as it's consistent and will quickly rule out all devices running older operating systems.

Once that's done, limit to device features by using UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in your Info.plist and opting for the front-facing camera (or flash). It's OK to say you need these capabilities to be present, even if you're not using them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` can help you out.

Comment: I know that "camera-flash" is only for iphone4, but my app does not use it, do I still need to add this requirement in my plist? I doubt if my app was built with iphone4 SDK, it may be automatically prevent from installing to a iphone3 device.